# Excel VBA copying a static range into a dynamic range on different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a few issues working this out as I'm new to VBA but I'm sure it has a pretty simple solution.

I'm essentially wanting to automate the addition of new data to a sheet.

Sheet: INB BASKET Cells: A2:I76 contains live links to another worksheet.
Basically I want to copy these as Values to Sheet IND TOTAL below the latest entry on a button press (not continually updating).

I've created a dynamic named range (PasteRange) in excel that selects the 75 rows below the last entry that I want to paste into:

```
=OFFSET('IND TOTAL'!$A$1,COUNTA('IND TOTAL'!$A:$A),0,75,9)
```

I've then created a module with the following:

```
Sub CopyRange()
Dim CopyFrom As Range

Set CopyFrom = Sheets("IND BASKET").Range("A2", [I76])
et PasteArea = Sheets("IND TOTAL").Range("PasteRange")

CopyFrom.Copy
PasteArea.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

But to no success as of yet, please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are only interested in pasting the values, then a direct value transfer is more efficient and does not involve the clipboard.

```
with Sheets("IND BASKET").Range("A2:I76")
    Sheets("IND TOTAL").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
end with
```

With your own Copy, Paste Special xlPasteValues you only need to specify the cell in the top-left corner of the destination and allow the copied area to define the size and shape.

```
Sheets("IND BASKET").Range("A2:I76").Copy
Sheets("IND TOTAL").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

The definition of your named range might be better without the volatile OFFSET function like,

```
=INDEX('IND TOTAL'!$A:$A, MATCH("zzz",'IND TOTAL'!$A:$A )+1):INDEX('IND TOTAL'!$I:$I, MATCH("zzz",'IND TOTAL'!$A:$A ) + 75)
'or for just the first cell
=INDEX('IND TOTAL'!$A:$A, MATCH("zzz",'IND TOTAL'!$A:$A )+1)
```

That assumes that column A contains text which I deduced by your use of COUNTA and not COUNT. If column A contains numbers, swap 1e99 for "zzz".

Comment: Direct value transfer sounds good and I suppose without the use of clipboard it's much less of a resource hog. 

Using the direct value transfer code you provided I get a bunch of errors, I added it below the "Set" commands and have tried it without the set commands and still to no avail.

Further, the definition of the named range doesn't select the correct area. The reason I tried to use offset was because I'm selecting the area below previous data. I'm looking into NextRow function to see if this provides a solution.

Comment: I've adjusted the named range definition to reflect teh full A:I width. The source ranges were created using your mashup of quoted cell reference and 'square bracket' reference. I've changed them to something closer to a conventional 'one-piece' range reference.

Comment: Yeh I changed it to reflect the full width earlier but it doesn't hang below the previous data. For example I already have 7 data sets (of 75 rows) in there so I want to add the next data from row 527 to 601.

Comment: Scratch that, it works! :D Thanks for the help @Jeeped